# Play Framework 1.2.5 dependency placed in project directory

Tags: playframework, crud

I'm trying to launch a play framework application with the following dependencies.yml file:

```
require:
- play 1.2.5
- play -> crud
```

When I run `play deps --sync`, I get this output:

```
Installing resolved dependencies,
~
~   modules/crud -> /Applications/play-1.2.5/modules/crud
~
~ Synchronizing, deleting unknown dependencies
~
~   Deleted: /project path/modules/crud
~
~
~ Done!
```

It seems that every time I run `play eclipsify`, for some reason play is putting the CRUD module in the project path, instead of just using the one already present in /Applications/play-1.2.5/.

The only way I've got it to work is adding `module.crud=${play.path}/modules/crud` in application.conf, but that breaks everything when I deploy it to Heroku where "CRUD has already been defined".

How can I force play to only use the modules in /Applications/play-1.2.5/ and not copy anything to the working directory?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you first remove the following line from the `conf/dependencies.yml`:

`- play -> crud`

And **then** add the following line into your `conf/application.conf`

`module.crud=${play.path}/modules/crud`

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same result - CRUD cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: What do you mean? In your question you said the result is "CRUD has already been defined", obviously it's not the same result if you received "CRUD cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: That's the problem when I'm deploying to Heroku. Locally, I can only define CRUD once (via application.conf), but defining it via dependencies.yml does NOT work. On Heroku, both work which is the reason it's telling me it has been defined already.

Comment: I've made some further progress - apparently, play does not create the symbolic links needed for CRUD within the project. I've created them manually and now it works, but this isn't exactly the solution I'd hoped for.

Comment: *On Heroku, both work which is the reason it's telling me it has been defined already* - this is exactly the reason I ask you to remove it from dependencies.yml file.